# Deployment to heroku [Error: spawn babel-node ENOENT]

Tags: node.js, heroku, compiler-errors, next.js

Project works perfectly on dev machine. I've already spent more than 5 hours:

- trying out different configurations using bash 'start' scripts on heroku remotely
- installing babel-cli and babel-preset-env as dependencies instead of devDependencies
- reading through heroku documentation about local builds, trying out
  them
- disabling dotenv in production

What are your suggestions / solution to this babel-node and heroku incompatibility? Maybe they're disabling it, since it makes more load on their server memory? I've written all my files in ES6 and I tried to rewrite them to old syntax, but that's almost impossible. Is there a way to make babel work on server-side for heroku?

**Heroku application log:**

```
2018-05-01T12:08:44.677261+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-05-01T12:08:47.873964+00:00 app[web.1]: [heroku-exec] Starting
2018-05-01T12:08:48.920661+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-05-01T12:08:48.920707+00:00 app[web.1]: > rearn@1.0.0 start /app
2018-05-01T12:08:48.920710+00:00 app[web.1]: > cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel-node server/server.js
2018-05-01T12:08:48.920712+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-05-01T12:08:49.196690+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:183
2018-05-01T12:08:49.196703+00:00 app[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2018-05-01T12:08:49.196704+00:00 app[web.1]:       ^
2018-05-01T12:08:49.196706+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-05-01T12:08:49.196709+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: spawn babel-node ENOENT
2018-05-01T12:08:49.196710+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
2018-05-01T12:08:49.196712+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
2018-05-01T12:08:49.196714+00:00 app[web.1]:     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
2018-05-01T12:08:49.196717+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
2018-05-01T12:08:49.196718+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
2018-05-01T12:08:49.196720+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:678:11)
2018-05-01T12:08:49.196721+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
2018-05-01T12:08:49.196723+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
2018-05-01T12:08:49.206967+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-05-01T12:08:49.208660+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2018-05-01T12:08:49.211774+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! rearn@1.0.0 start: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel-node server/server.js`
2018-05-01T12:08:49.212391+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-05-01T12:08:49.212731+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2018-05-01T12:08:49.212944+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the rearn@1.0.0 start script.
2018-05-01T12:08:49.213151+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-05-01T12:08:49.220087+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-05-01T12:08:49.220400+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-05-01T12:08:49.220579+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-05-01T12_08_49_214Z-debug.log
2018-05-01T12:08:49.315806+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-05-01T12:08:49.301459+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "rearn",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.9.3",
    "npm": "5.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel-node server/server.js",
    "test": "eslint pages components lib",
    "dev": "nodemon server/server.js --watch server --exec babel-node server/server.js",
    "port": "cross-env PORT=4000 npm start",
    "prod": "yarn build && cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel-node server/server.js",
    "precommit": "yarn test",
    "prepush": "yarn test",
    "heroku-postbuild": "YARN_PRODUCTION=false yarn install && yarn build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^0.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "^4.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^2.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
    "dotenv": "^5.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-useragent": "^1.0.12",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.15",
    "next": "5.1.0",
    "next-offline": "^2.5.0",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^1.3.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-popper": "^0.10.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-form": "^7.3.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "styled-jsx": "^2.2.6",
    "workbox-background-sync": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "eslint": "4.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-compat": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
    "husky": "^0.14.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: I must add that build succeeds perfectly with no errors. Error is thrown on page load.

Answer (score 2):

Solved. Actually I was removing and installing babel-cli and babel-preset-env in bash and somehow heroku didn't update package.json remotely? Why? Solution:

- installing babel-cli and babel-preset-env as dependencies instead of
  devDependencies (actually babel-cli only is enough for next.js, as it uses latest babel config).

Answer (score 1):

Found this post, since i had a similar problem.
moved the whole block of

```
"@babel/cli": "7.5.5",
"@babel/core": "7.5.5",
"@babel/node": "7.5.5",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.5.5",
"@babel/preset-env": "7.5.5",
"@babel/runtime": "7.5.5",
```

from devDepenencies to the dependencies section of package.json = problem solved for now, maybe not the final perfect solution, tough